# How can I prevent a ListView option from changing?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

How can I prevent a `ListView` option from changing?

I have tried the following, however it still changes:

```
bool q=false;
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (q)
    {
        // Let change happen
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Stop change from happening
        return;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think it's attempting to make the selection constant basically or preventing the update in certain cases anyways... But the second piece of code threw me for a loop.

Comment: Not sure what the question is...

Comment: How to control the list of options can be changed to select an item

Comment: Stop to change the selected item

Comment: I apologize to you because of poor english writing :)

Comment: @user1201996 I hope you don't mind, but I updated the question to make it more understandable. I hope I understood your original version correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the prior value and then reset it to the prior.

```
int lastIndex = -1;

if (q)
{
    lastIndex = (ListView)Sender.SelectedIndex;
} 
else 
{
    // Stop change from happening
    (ListView)Sender.SelectedIndex = lastIndex;
}
```

Comment: How to get SelectedIndex before selectItem change.

Comment: See lastIndex.  That should be the SelectedIndex before selectItem change.